# JavaScript: Pass a variable from one function to another, using setInterval()?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

So I have a function that loops executing a function, example:

```
function(f){
  var variable;
  for(z = 0; z < 10; z++){
    variable = "cool";         
    setInterval(f)
  }
```

Btw, the real function is MUCH more complex than this but it's the same theory.
I want to be able to execute the function in argument *f* and set some variables (ex. *variable*) so that this function can use them, in a whole this is the idea:

```
function say(f){
   var variable = "hey";
   setInterval(f);
}
say(function(){
   alert(variable)
});
```

Here, one should get an alert box saying *hey*. That's the theory, but it wont work:

> Variable "variable" isn't defined

The browser will probably just ignore the error and alert *undefined*.

But anyways, how do I "pass" the variable **without changing the scope of it**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer to have a function without parameter, you could consider using the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method:

```
function say(f){
   var variable = "hey";
   setInterval(function() { 
       f.call(variable); // set the context
   }, 1000);
}
say(function(){
    alert(this);
});
```

Comment: This is, in my opinion, the BEST method, thanks! The other ones are *almost* the same, but this one just looks cleaner, and is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript has [**closures**](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/), so you **can** do this:

```
var x = 0;
setInterval(function() {
   //do something with x
}, 1000);
```

In your specific case, you should do this:

```
function say(f){
   var variable = "hey";
   setInterval(function() { 
       f(variable); //invoke the say function's passed-in "f" function, passing in "hey"
   }, 1000);
}
say(function(arg){
    //arg will be "hey"
    alert(arg);
});
```

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) takes *two* arguments, the second being the amount of time (in milliseconds) that you wish to delay execution of the passed-in function reference.

Comment: I know the setInterval takes two arguments. Setting the second one to zero is *almost* the same as not setting it, it will execute in no amount of time. Just a easy way of executing things, even though there are other (probably better) ways.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the lambda function is coming from another scope, you can't use a closure to get the value in the function directly. You'll have to pass the value to your function directly via a closure, and be prepared to receive it in the lambda:

```
function say(f){
   var variable = "hey";
   setInterval( function(){ f(variable) }, 500 );
}
say(function(yyy){
   alert(yyy);
});
```

Comment: What's lambda lol, anyways, it's a good method even though I prefer not to rely on the existence of an argument at "the other side" (in this case *yyy*)

Answer (score 1):

```
function say(f){
  var variable = "hey";
  setInterval(function(){
    f.call(null, variable);
  }, 1000);
}
say(function(variable){
   alert(variable)
});
```

By using the [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method on the function.

Comment: Fixed it now; although does not look clean anymore.

Comment: Wise, even though *f(variable)* is cleaner ;)
EDIT: Even though I'll end up using the *call* method